# Category not being selected

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to build multiple loops for different parts of my page but I can't isolate a category.

I just get to see every post the category is ignored.

Below my code, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I'm somewhat at a loss what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

```
<div id="postblokcontainer">
    <?php
    $first_query = new WP_Query('cat=Postblok');
    while($first_query->have_posts()) : $first_query->the_post(); ?>
    <article id="postblok">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>


        <h3> </h3>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <ul class="socmed">
            <li><img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/mockup.jpg"></li>

        </ul>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cat` parameter [takes an ID](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) and not the category name or slug. If you want to use the slug you need `category_name` but it must be the slug.

```
$first_query = new WP_Query('category_name=postblok');
```

Other category parameters are:

```
    cat (int) - use category id.
    category_name (string) - use category slug (NOT name).
    category__and (array) - use category id.
    category__in (array) - use category id.
    category__not_in (array) - use category id.
```